# Java: Get properties of an object by parsing XML-file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom

I got a question regarding XML and parsing it. I use JDOM to parse my XML-File, but I got a little Problem.

A sample of my XML-File looks like this:

```
 <IO name="Bus" type="Class">
    <ResourceAttribute name="Bandwidth" type="KiloBitPerSecond" value="50" />
 </IO>
```

Bus is a object instance of the class IO. The object got the name and type properties. Additional it has some attributes, like in the sample, the Attribute Bandwidth with the value of 50 and the datatype KiloBitPerSecond.

So when I want to loop over the file with:

```
    for(Element packages : listPackages)
        {
                Map<String, Values> valueMap = new HashMap<String, Values>();
                List<Element> objectInstanceList = packages.getChildren();

                for(Element objects : objectInstanceList) 
                {
                    List<Element> listObjectClasses = objects.getChildren();

                    for(Element classes : listObjectClasses) 
                    {
                    List<Element> listObjectAttributes = classes.getChildren();

                        for(Element objectAttributes : listObjectAttributes)
                        {
                            List<Attribute> listAttributes = objectAttributes.getAttributes();

                            for(Attribute attributes : listAttributes)
                            {

                            String name = attributes.getName();
                            String value = attributes.getValue();
                            AttributeType datatype = attributes.getAttributeType();
                            Values v = new Values(name, datatype, value);
                            valueMap.put(classes.getName(), v);
                            System.out.println(name + ":" + value);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                                        }
                //System.out.println(valueMap);
         }
```

values is a class which defines the object attribute:

```
public class Values{
 private String name;
 //private AttributeType datatype;
 private String value;
```

Thats the rest of the Code. I got two question relating that. The first one got more priority at the moment.

1. How do I get the values of the object(Attribute.Name = Bandwidth; Attribute.Value = 50) ? Istead that I get

   name:Bus
    type:Class

   I thought about an additional for-loop, but the JDOM class attribute dont have a method called getAttributes().
2. Thats just second priority because without question 1 I cannot go further. As you see in the sample, an Attribute got 3 properties, name, type and value. How can I extract that triple put of the sample. JDOM seems just to know 2  properties for an Attribute, name and value.

thanks a lot in advance and hopefully I managed to express my self.

Edit: Added an additional for-loop in it, so the output now is:

```
name:Bandwidth
type:KiloBitPerSecond
value:50
```

That means name is the name of that property and value is the value of name. Didnt know that. At least question one is clearer now and I can try working on 2, but the new information makes 2 clearer to me.

Comment: You should be using recursion to parse your xml

Comment: values should be Values in accordance to java naming convention, classes should start with a capital letter

Comment: Maybe you are confused by the name "ResourceAttribute"? This is an XML element (and not an XML attribute). And of course, attributes do not have atributes.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes you are right, was confused a bit, but fixed it already myself, thanks.

Comment: If this is new code I would suggest using JAXB instead, then you don't have to do any parsing. Just put some annotations in your object and call a few lines to convert the XML into a Java object. If you have to use jdom just ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

In xml the opening tag of `element`s are encosoed between `<` and `>` (or `/>`) , after the `<` comes the name of the element, then comes a list of `attributes` in the format `name="value"`. An element can be closed inline with `/>` or with a closing tag `</[element name]>`

It would be preferable to use recursion to parse your xml instead of badly readable/maintainable nested for loops.

Here is how it could look like:

```
@Test
public void parseXmlRec() throws JDOMException, IOException {
    String xml = "<root>"
            + "<Package>"
            + "<IO name=\"Bus\" type=\"Class\">\r\n" + 
            "    <ResourceAttribute name=\"Bandwidth\" type=\"KiloBitPerSecond\" value=\"50\" />\r\n" + 
            " </IO>"
            + "</Package>"
            + "</root>";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
    Document document = sb.build(is);
    is.close();

    Element root = document.getRootElement();
    List<Element> children = root.getChildren();
    for(Element element : children) {
        parseelement(element);
    }
}

private void parseelement(Element element) {
    System.out.println("Element:" + element.getName());
    String name = element.getAttributeValue("name");
    if(name != null) {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);    
    }
    String type = element.getAttributeValue("type");
    if(type != null) {
        System.out.println("type: " + type);
    }
    String value = element.getAttributeValue("value");
    if(value != null) {
        System.out.println("value: " + value);
    }
    List<Element> children = element.getChildren();
    if(children != null) {
        for(Element child : children) {
            parseelement(child);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Element: Package
Element: IO
name: Bus
type: Class
Element: ResourceAttribute
name: Bandwidth
type: KiloBitPerSecond
value: 50
```

While parsing, check the name of each element and instanciate the coresponding objects. For that I would suggest to write a separate method to handle each element. For example:

```
void parsePackage(Element packageElement) { ... }
parseIO(Element ioElement) { ... }
void parseResourceAttribute(Element resourceAttributeElement) { ... }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is your code still valid for any kind of input? The XML- sample was just one single Line. My file contains my elements and attributes and I dont know the number, so the code must be suitable for any kind of input. The for-loops are maybe not so beautiful, but for me as a newbie, it was much easier to implement.

Comment: @Alika87 well, for elements yes, but as you see, on each element it checks only for the attributes `name`, `type` and `value`. Just run it against you input document and see the output. You need to know the structure of your xml document and for each element create a separate method as a method for parsing it. In each method loop over the children and call the corresponding method for each element.